# Exercises related to the definition of surjectivity and injectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I don't know how to go about this exercise:

I need to give examples of both

(i) a non surjective function $f\colon A \to B$ such that for, some subset $B' \subset B$, I can prove that $f(f^{-1}(B'))\neq B'$, and

(ii) a non injective function $g: A \to B$ such that, for some subset $A' \subset A$, I can prove that $g^{-1}(g(A'))\neq A'$.

Comment: Can you think of any non-surjective functions? Do they suffice for (i)? If not, in what way do they fail? How can you fix this? Similarly for (ii).

Comment: I recommend that you begin as simple as possible. For example, take $A$ and $B$ to be sets of, say, two elements each.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a constant map $f\colon A\to B$.

(i) take $B'=\{b\}$ where $b$ does not belong to the image of $f$

(ii) take as $A'$ any proper subset of $A$

(One needs that both $A$ and $B$ have more than one element.)

Comment: Your suggestion for (ii) is incorrect. Take $A=\{1,2,3\}$. $B=\{a,b\}$, $g(1)=a$, $g(2)=g(3)=b$. If I take the proper subset $A'=\{1\}$. then $g(A') = \{a\}$ and $g^{-1}(g(A')) = g^{-1}(\{a\}) = \{1\} = A'$.

Comment: this is not constant mapping ??????? you do not know what the constant map mean ??

Comment: My suggestion is true and your example do not express about my suggestion.(the constant map is the one that takes all the domain to one point in the codomain).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The given hint is to use a *constant* map, not any map.

Comment: <Shrug> You initial write-up was so crowded and hard to read, it was difficult to understand what clauses applied to which clauses. You can and should thank egreg for cleaning it up for you.

Comment: Many books are written by this way. The important thing is that scientifically correct.